Is there a way to filter systemd cgroup user slices by group/gid so we can allocate resources to specific groups of users?
It looks like you can add conditions to the unit section of systemd unit files, so I was thinking... is there a way to add the condition ConditionGroup to a drop-in under user-.slice.d? My end goal is to have weighted CPU allocations for a group of contractors so if 100% of CPU is used they will get 33% of those resources.
The only drop-in I have is the one that came installed on Ubuntu 20.04 at /lib/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/10-defaults.conf
[Unit]
Description=User Slice of UID %j
Documentation=man:user@.service(5)
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Slice]
TasksMax=33%

Could I make a copy that uses the ConditionGroup for a specific group and add CPU weights for that group?
[Unit]
Description=User Slice of UID %j
Documentation=man:user@.service(5)
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
StopWhenUnneeded=yes
ConditionGroup=<some group GID>

[Slice]
CPUWeight=3333

Then add CPUWeight=6666 to the 10-default.conf so anyone not in the ConditionGroup will receive a larger share of the CPU? If this is possible, I'm not 100% sure where to place the copy of the drop-in or what to call it. Any help or advice on how to accomplish this otherwise would be great.

Systemd doesn't support this natively, but you could set up pam_exec in /etc/pam.d so that it prepares an individual drop-in for the UID whose session is being opened and places it in /run/systemd/... before pam_systemd gets to create the actual slice.

session optional pam_exec.so /etc/systemd/fixslice.sh
session optional pam_systemd.so


#!/bin/sh
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" = "open_session" ]; then
    uid=$(id -u "$PAM_USER")
    unit="user-$UID.slice"
    dir="/run/systemd/system/$unit.d"
    ...
fi

Alternatively, use pam_exec after pam_systemd, and have it call systemctl set-property.

Wouldn't I need to "systemctl daemon-reload" after adding the drop-in on the fly?

Only if the unit is already loaded into memory – which it won't be, because systemd-logind hasn't created it yet.
